# Limit the length of text shown in the HTML File Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, forms

[image: File Input]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jasny bootstrap -->
<script src="https://skblue.com/m3workx/sb-admin/vendor/jasny-bootstrap/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://skblue.com/m3workx/sb-admin/vendor/jasny-bootstrap/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://skblue.com/m3workx/sb-admin/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://skblue.com/m3workx/sb-admin/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<script defer src="https://skblue.com/m3workx/fontawesome/js/packs/light.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://skblue.com/m3workx/fontawesome/js/packs/regular.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://skblue.com/m3workx/fontawesome/js/packs/solid.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://skblue.com/m3workx/fontawesome/js/fontawesome.min.js"></script>

                                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group <-imageerror->" data-provides="fileinput" style="max-width: 500px;">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-image"></i></span>
                                  <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
                                  <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Afbeelding Selecteren</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Veranderen</span><input type="file" name="vehicleimage" id="vehicleimage" accept="image/*"></span>
                                  <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Verwijderen</a>
                                </div>
```

On a website I'm developing I have an input field for an image. It looks nice until the length of the filename becomes greater than x. So is there a way I can show a substring of the filename in the field so it becomes something like:

```
Screen Shot 2017-09...
```

This is what I found:

```
           var limit = 8;

            var fileName = document.getElementById("vehicleimage").value();

            // get both parts
            var fileNameExtension = "." + fileName.split(".").pop();
            var fileNameBase = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length()-fileNameExtension.length());

            if(fileNameBase.length()>limit){
                // now limit it and set it as fileName
                fileName = fileNameBase.substring(0, limit) + '...' + fileNameExtension;
            }
            document.getElementById("vehicleimage").value = fileName;
```

But that doesn't change what the user sees. So my question is, how can I achieve this with jquery or javascript?

Comment: Btw. the <-imageerror-> tag in the div class attribute get's replaced by php so that can be ignored

Comment: I think it would work put inputs it inside <div class="form-group"> and addclass to input class="form-control"

Comment: Make a working snippet pls

Comment: I added the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to truncate it using CSS?

```
#vehicleimage {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing this line:

```
<div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
```

with this:

```
<div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput" ><span class="fileinput-filename" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 1; line-height: 1; max-height: 1*1;"></span></div>
```